# IdentityServer: Open site2 front page from site1 with the same user

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an spa application .net core/angular and Identity server/Open IdConnect authentication. I have to be able to open another application from the site1 page. The user is the same but client id's are different. Something like this:
[image]

Is it possible to do it? I'm looking at this option but not sure whether it will work for me: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html?highlight=delegation#extension-grants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to redirect to the login screen for site2, I assume? Otherwise it would already work by default.
You could consider using JWT authentication for site2 and just retrieve a JWT from site1, considering site2 to be an API resource rather than a UI website.

Comment: Right, it shouldn't be redirected to login screen, just open site2. Could you please give a short example on how could I 'retrieve a JWT from site1' or give a link to docs, I'm rather new to OpenId connect. Thanks.

Comment: [Here's](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) a good overview of setting up both the Site1 (The ASP.NET Core application in the example) and Site2 (the API in the example).